# keyboard's wifi LED doesn't work properly

Tags: kali-linux, broadcom

My keyboard's wifi LED should normally be orange when turned off , blue when turned on, but it's always orange and that makes me uncomfortable.

Here are some outputs I think are useful:

```
root@Machine:~# uname -a
Linux Machine 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2kali1 (2017-06-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@Machine:~# lspci | grep Wireless
44:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
root@Machine:~# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a2:b2:d6:d5:4a:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd4800000-d4820000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 236821  bytes 65224834 (62.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 236821  bytes 65224834 (62.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::7670:459e:2cde:75ea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd9c:c172:b03b:ce00:204c:8ad8:2f5:d85b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 26:26:10:c2:d4:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 111523  bytes 113324698 (108.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 112290  bytes 26144479 (24.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@Machine:~# iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"3bdo"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: 9C:C1:72:B0:3B:D4   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:275  Invalid misc:1391   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

PS: I have installed `broadcom-sta-dkms`, `broadcom-sta-common` and `broadcom-sta-source` before, but I removed them because they were very problematic (keeps asking for wifi password over and over making me unable to access any router, doesn't open monitor mode).

Comment: Probably the driver doesn't know how to control the LED properly, because this is different for different hardware (different GPIO, or whatever), and your hardware is different. Does it worry you enough you want to debug the driver? Can you program in C, or does it worry you enough you want to learn C for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the module I use, changing the module from `brcmsmac` to `wl` will resolve the problem; by running the following (after adding `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`) 
 :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```